# Dynamically import classes in Visual Basic

Tags: python, vb.net, class, import

I'm working on a school project which need to be done in Visual Basic. For this I'm porting one of my Python project in this programming language, project which (in Python) is scanning a directory for .py files and then imports them (dynamically) with the `__import__` statement, at runtime. It is possible to do this in Visual Basic with .DLL classes?

Thank you

Comment: VB.net (need some words to write here, heh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load assemblies dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName)` and then get the assembly information, enumerate the types, create instance of those types, etc. The details depend on what exactly you want this DLLs for.

When you have the Type for the object you want to create, you can use code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578495/dynamically-create-an-object-of-type) that uses [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(VS.71).aspx) method.

You can find some (C#) samples in one of my projects: http://code.earlsoft.co.uk/hg/builderpro/file/41046067e90e/Library/Extensions/Extension.cs
http://code.earlsoft.co.uk/hg/builderpro/file/41046067e90e/Library/ActionInfo/ActionInfo.cs

Comment: So, if I have a class "DummyPlugin" in DLL, how I create an instance  of it in my Main Application? Sorry if this it's a dumb question, but I'm very newbie in VB.Net and all this Microsoft stuff...

Comment: I've added a bit on calling Activator.CreateInstance.

Comment: Oh, sorry :) Yout information was helpful, leading me to find the solution for my question. Currently I'm on Linux, but I'll post more details after I'll continue working on this project.

Anyway, thank you a lot!