# C++ Constructor from Type

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

In C# an object can be created based on knowledge of the desired type like this (among a few other ways)

```
public T GetInstance<T>(string type)
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type));
}
```

**Is there an equivalent way of doing this in native c++?**

I have a `base` class and a `derived` class. I wish to construct the proper object based on stored data. I have control over what this stored data is, but I need to know what information needs to be stored to identify the type and then how to use that data to later call a constructor.

I'm essentially looking for the c++ answer to this question: [Dynamically create an object of <Type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578495/dynamically-create-an-object-of-type)

Comment: reflection is not possible in C++. But if you know what data you have stored, you can use polymorphism

Comment: I know reflection doesn't exist. I'm just using the c# example to outline the goal that I have. I'm sure the solution involves typical c++ classes and inheritance but I'm a bit lost at the moment on how to accomplish this.

Comment: `base* b = nullptr; if (DATA == SOME_DATA) { b = new base(); } else if (DATA == SOME_OTHER_DATA) { b = new derived(); } /* work with b, or return it*/`

Comment: I don't wish to hard-code the possible derived types.

Comment: `template<class T, class...Args> base* createBase(T&& dummy, Args...&& args) { return new T(args...); }`. Sorry if the variadic template has incorrect syntax, I only worked with it once or twice.

Comment: You are looking for the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) concept.

Comment: Does `Activator.CreateInstance` not `hard-code the possible derived types` ?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` is part of .Net Framework so no it does not hardcode since it is able to instantiate custom types.