# Instantiate Dynamic Classes

Tags: c#, class

I want to create an array that holds different objects within an inheritance paradigm. I have an **item** class that several other classes to be inherited. My goal is to put different objects that inherit **item** into an array. I won't know the type of object and thus will need to instantiate an object of an unknown type.

I've been following this Stackoverflow question: [Dynamically create an object of  < Type>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/578500/3630407) and different variations of it.

```
using System;

const int _size= 3;
private Item[] _slots = new Item[_size];


// Method to place objects in array
// item here may be Carrot or Potato or another object
public void AddToBackpack(Item item) {

   // Dynamically create Item object
   var newItem = GetInstance<Item>(item.ToString());

   // Find object in _slots array of similar type and merge newItem with it.

}


public T GetInstance<T>(string type) {
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type));
}



// Classes
public class Carrot : Item {
    public Carrot() {
        _stackLimit = 5;
    }
}

public class Potato : Item {
    public Potato() {
        _stackLimit = 3;
    }
}

public abstract class Item {
    public int _stackLimit { get; set; } = 1;
    public int _stackSize { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

**Here is the error I'm getting when I try and and call Activator.CreateInstance**

```
Run-time exception (line -1): Request failed.

Stack Trace:

[System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.]
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Submission#0.GetInstance[T](String type)
   at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptExecutionState.<RunSubmissionsAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Change `GetInstance` to take a `Type` parameter and use `item.GetType()` to get the type to pass to it. `Type.GetType` is ... "tempermental". Plus, using `ToString` on an instance to get the type name works if you haven't overridden `ToString` but it's not the right way to do it if you know you want the type name (use `item.GetType().Name` instead).

Comment: Why would your `GetInstance<T>` method both use a generic type parameter for the desired type and also a string with the name of the desired type? One of them is redundant and therefore unnecessary...

Comment: None of this looks right; if you have an instance of `Item` in hand, why are you creating a new one?

Comment: @madreflection thanks I'll give that a try.

Comment: @EricLippert I've removed a bunch of code for simplicity sake. I have to create a new one to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you use reflection here. Maybe i do not understand your use-case but, You are passing `Item item` what is `Carrot` or `Potato` and then you want to create the same object using reflection... why you just do not use passed instance ?

but to solve your problem try:

```cs
// change this method like this 
public void AddToBackpack(Item item) {

   // Dynamically create Item object
   var newItem = GetInstance<Item>(item.GetType());

   // Find object in _slots array of similar type and merge newItem with it.

}

// and this method like this
public T GetInstance<T>(Type type) {
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

or Make it more generic

```cs
// change this method like this 
public void AddToBackpack<T>(T item) where T: Item
 {

   // Dynamically create Item object
   var newItem = GetInstance<T>();

   // Find object in _slots array of similar type and merge newItem with it.

}

// and this method like this
public T GetInstance<T>() {
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 
}
```